# Best way to using Global Variables in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, global-variables, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

I want to use variables over PowerShell instances away.
(I know that global variables are not nice)
Is this the best way to define a variable over instances in PowerShell? Other ideas?
($global:variable is not over PowerShell instances away)

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable", "Test value.", "User")

[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable","User")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Other options would be to:

- Write/read a hashtable to a settings file using Export/Import-CliXml.
- Stash information in the user's registry hive.

But adding a user environment variable is also a good way to go and the way you suggest is what is needed for the environment changes to survive exiting the current PowerShell session.

Comment: Yea, I would suggest using a file over using the registry, and the registry over using the environment variables.